# GARCH estimation for subsamples

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, garch

I would like to apply a GARCH(1,1) model for subsamples at time intervals length $k\delta$ on a stock return time series $\big(r(i\delta,(i+1)\delta)\big)_{i=0}^{kq-1}$ each element of which is the return between time $i\delta$ and $(i+1)\delta$. I take the recursion formula to be
$$h(t,t+k\delta) = c+a\,u(t-k\delta,t)^2 +b\,h(t-k\delta,t) \tag1$$
where $h(t-k\delta,t)$ is the estimated variance for the  and $r(t-k\delta,t)$ is the return for time interval $(t-k\delta,t)$. Suppose the prices are observed at shorter time intervals of length $\delta$. I would like to use them for Equation (1).

Is it correct to use the following expression?
$$u(t-k\delta,t)^2 := \sum_{i=1}^k r\big(t-i\delta,t-(i-1)\delta\big)^2 \tag2$$
If so, when I use the maximum likelihood to estimate the parameters $(a,b,c)$, is it legitimate to apply it on the returns $r(t-k\delta,t)$. Note that $r(t-k\delta,t)^2\neq u(t-k\delta,t)^2$. $\big(u(jk\delta,(j+1)k\delta)\big)_{j=0}^{q-1}$ forms a new time series. Its Gaussian negative logarithmic likelihood
$$l(a,b,c):=\sum_{j=0}^{q-1} \bigg( \frac{u(jk\delta,(j+1)k\delta)^2}{h(jk\delta,(j+1)k\delta)}+\ln h(jk\delta,(j+1)k\delta)\bigg).$$
Equivalently, we can substitute $u$ as the magnitude of the return into a canonical GARCH estimator to obtain the parameters $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: What is $u(\cdot)$? Is $r$ really a function of $r$ in $(2)$?

Comment: @RichardHardy: $u(\cdot)$ is defined in Equation $(2)$. It is the estimation of the variance of $r(t-k\delta,t)$. I have edited the question to make it clearer. Please review.

Comment: Again, is $r$ supposed to be a function of $r$ as currently specified in $(2)$?

Comment: @RichardHardy: I have corrected the typo. Please review. Do you have any comment on the methodology?

Comment: Sorry, no, not at the moment.